# How to restore android phone from Google cloud backup to a new phone when unlock pattern is not recognized?

Tags: restore, android-11, google-backup

I broke my phone (Android 10). I have a new phone (Android 11).
I tried to restore data from Google cloud backup, but it asks for the unlock pattern of the old phone.
I know the pattern, however, I cannot enter it on the new phone. I have the same dot twice in my unlock pattern, and the new phone just won't recognize the same dot the second time. Now, it says it will delete all my backup data if I fail to enter the correct pattern 5 more times.
How can I access my backup data and restore it to my new phone?
Thanks.

Comment: **I have the same dot twice in my unlock pattern**  Not possible by Android design